# appending the dialog box form data as a new column in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`#dialog-form` contains two radio buttons. On selecting "Audi" value from drop down dialog a form appears. On selecting "yes" and clicking on save I want to append the `yes` value as a new `td` to only the row where we selected value but this script is appending to all the rows.

I also tried using `$.closest` `tr` and it didn’t worked for me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Save": addUser,
            Cancel: function() {
                $("#dialog-form").dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
    $(".d1").on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'audi') {
            $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
        }
    });

    function addUser(){
        var selected = $("#dialog-form input[type='radio']:checked");
        
        if(selected.length > 0 && selected.val() == "Yes") {
            $('.mainTable tr').append("<td>" + selected.val() + "</td>");
            $("#dialog-form").dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"
        integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table border="0" id="mainTable" class="mainTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="select">Online Password (Repeated)&nbsp;</td>
        <td><select name="D1" class="d1">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select></td>
        <!-- input textbox i want to disable-->
        <td><input type="text" value="" class="d2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="select">Online Password (Repeated)&nbsp;</td>
        <td><select name="D1" class="d1">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" class="d2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="select">Online Password (Repeated)&nbsp;</td>
        <td><select name="D1" class="d1">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select></td>
         <td><input type="text" value="" class="d2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
 </table>

 <div id="dialog-form">
     <form>
         <label for="name">Select smart safe Yes or No</label><br>
         <input type="radio" name="smart" value="Yes" checked> YES<br>
         <input type="radio" name="smart" value="No"> NO<br>
     </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vijayram8787/h3foepr2/

Comment: you will need to keep somewhere reference to the changed select. For example, when You are opening your modal save to the variable var whichSelect = this;, and then use whichSelect with jquery to get desired tr

$(whichSelect).parent().append()...

Comment: cool, i should appreciate your patience too :) thanx for the enlightenment

Comment: thanks :)) and good luck :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign selected option to a variable and then take closest "tr" and append new "td" into it.

```
**var that = '';**
  $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
           "Save": addUser,
        Cancel: function() {
          $("#dialog-form").dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
            });
   $(".d1").on('change', function() {
   if ($(this).val() == 'audi') {
            **that = $(this);**
             $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");

                    }
                      }); 

    function addUser(){
    var selected = $("#dialog-form input[type='radio']:checked");

    if(selected.length > 0 && selected.val()=="Yes"){


        **that.closest("tr").append("<td>" + selected.val() + "</td>");**
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("close");
    }
    }
```

I have also added jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/vkm193/uzrfy6q7/1/

Comment: thanx for the fix but any particular reason y $(this).closest(tr) is not working here

Comment: $(this).closest(tr) is working. I have added fiddle. Is it not working at your end?

Comment: the code what u provided is working , but i tried this way $(this).closest("tr").append("<td>" + selected.val() + "</td>");                               it didnt work for me any bug in the above line?

Comment: Alright, I got your point. If you would have been using $(this) in your adduser function directly, it would be representing the invoking element of adduser function and that is why you were not getting the desired result. If you notice I am assigning '$(this)' to 'that' and then further I am using that. Hope I am able to clear your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for you from my comment

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var whichSelect = null;
  $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
           "Save": addUser,
        Cancel: function() {
          $("#dialog-form").dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
            });
   $(".d1").on('change', function() {
   if ($(this).val() == 'audi') {
            whichSelect = this;
             $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");

                    }
                      }); 

    function addUser(){
    var selected = $("#dialog-form input[type='radio']:checked");

    if(selected.length > 0 && selected.val()=="Yes"){


        $(whichSelect).parent().parent().append("<td>" + selected.val() + "</td>");
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("close");
    }
    }
  });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3foepr2/1/)

Comment: thanx a ton but can you just explain this part $(whichSelect).parent().parent()

Comment: sure! so we need to get parent [td] and then next parent [tr], you can try to improve this and get direct tr parent, I wanted to give you direction :))

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var selectElement;
  $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
        Save: function() {
          var selected = $("#dialog-form input[type='radio']:checked");
          if(selected.length > 0 && selected.val()=="Yes"){
              selectElement.closest("tr").append("<td>" + selected.val() + "</td>");
          }
          $("#dialog-form").dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $("#dialog-form").dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
            });
   $(".d1").on('change', function() {
      selectElement = $(this);
     if ($(this).val() == 'audi') {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
      }
   }); 

    function addUser(){
   
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<table border="0" id="mainTable" class="mainTable">
    <tr>
      <td class="select">Online Password (Repeated)&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <select name="D1" class="d1">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" class="d2">
        <!-- above is the input textbox i want to disable-->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="select">Online Password (Repeated)&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <select name="D1" class="d1">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" class="d2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="select">Online Password (Repeated)&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <select name="D1" class="d1">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" class="d2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
  </table>
<div id="dialog-form" >
    <form>
    <label for="name">Select smart safe Yes or No</label> <br>
      <input type="radio" name="smart" value="Yes" checked> YES<br>
  <input type="radio" name="smart" value="No"> NO<br>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thanx but any reason for commenting the add user function?